# ring with equal area to a circle

Tags: geometry

can you tell me please an example or an equation that I can plug in values, so that I will find the external and internal radii of a ring that has the same area as a specific radius circle? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming I understood the question, there are many possibilities for any given circle. If for example the radius of the circle is 1, we seek $R,r$ such that $\pi R^2-\pi r^2=\pi$ Meaning $ R^2-r^2=1$.

If we choose $r=1$, then $R=\sqrt2$. And if we choose $r=2$, then $R=\sqrt 5$.
In general of course, if the radius of the circle is $a$, any positive solution for $R^2-r^2=a^2$ will do.